# I am stuck on figuring out how to end the recursion loops as soon as the list number(s) is found

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a program that, using an array list of given integers (listOfNumbers), will find if any combination of sums of these numbers will add up to another given integer (CompareTo). This program uses recursion. I am stuck on figuring out how to end the recursion loops as soon as the list number(s) is found. Thanks.

```
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = listOfNumbers.size() - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        int backup = listOfNumbers.get(i);
        listOfNumbers.remove(i);
        for(int k = 0; k < listOfNumbers.size(); k ++)
        {
            sum += listOfNumbers.get(k);
        }
        if(sum == compareTo)
        {
            //IF THIS IS TRUE KILL ALL RECURSION
            return listOfNumbers;
        }

        sum = 0;
        answer(listOfNumbers, compareTo); //CREATE NEW RECURSION LOOP
        listOfNumbers.add(i, backup);
    }

    //IF NO COMBINATION OF ARRAY LIST NUMBERS WILL 
    //ADD TO = COMPARETO, RETURN ORIGINAL LIST
    return listOfNumbers;
```

Comment: Could you post the whole program? I can't figure out where is the recursion here and the first call to the function

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare first, and then add or remove numbers in the list. If you remove numbers before the recursive call, in subsequent returns the condition isn't meet.

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = listOfNumbers.size() - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    if(sum == compareTo)
    {
        //IF THIS IS TRUE KILL ALL RECURSION
        return listOfNumbers;
    }
    else
    {
        int backup = listOfNumbers.get(i);
        listOfNumbers.remove(i);
        for(int k = 0; k < listOfNumbers.size(); k ++)
        {
            sum += listOfNumbers.get(k);
        }

        sum = 0;
        answer(listOfNumbers, compareTo); //CREATE NEW RECURSION LOOP
        listOfNumbers.add(i, backup);
    }
}

//IF NO COMBINATION OF ARRAY LIST NUMBERS WILL 
//ADD TO = COMPARETO, RETURN ORIGINAL LIST
return listOfNumbers;
```

In fact, I would put the obvious case (sum == compareTo) in the very top of everything, and then do the rest of the stuff.

```
for(int k = 0; k < listOfNumbers.size(); k ++)
{
   sum += listOfNumbers.get(k);
}
if(sum == compareTo)
{
   //IF THIS IS TRUE KILL ALL RECURSION
   return listOfNumbers;
}
// DO THE REST OF OPERATIONS HERE....
```